# C++ error: The token '&&' is not a valid statement separator in this version

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

when i press "run task"task i have this error:
The token '&&' is not a valid statement separator in this version

```
+ CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidEndOfLine
```

```
{
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "Run C++ Program: g++.exe ",
            "command": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe -g3 -Wall \"${file} -o \"${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe\" &&\"${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe\"",
            
            "options": {
                "cwd": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            
            "detail": "компилятор: C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe"
```

[image]

Comment: This is not a C++ question. But it seems you are using " within a string in ". Those negate each other

Comment: `when i press "run task" ...`  Press where? Are you asking about some editor?

Comment: Pretty sure they're using vscode

Comment: Do you need a space between the `&&` and the escaped `"`, as in `&& \"`?

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a closing double-quote:

```
...\\g++.exe -g3 -Wall \"${file} -o ...
```

You don't end the file name with a quote.